# copy files from one remote machine to another

Tags: scp

I work at a university, and we have a remote machine(1) that I ssh into.

To do this from my laptop, I believe that I have to first ssh into the university system and then ssh into the particular machine. This all happens automatically for me because the ssh config file has been set up for me. I just type:

```
ssh -Y comp_name
```

and I'm in.

I'm currently trying to ssh FROM a totally unrelated remove machine(2) - nothing to do with the university. To ssh from this into my remote_machine(1), I do two separate ssh's:

```
1. Into the university (ssh-gateway)
2. Into remote_machine(1)
```

So far so good.

What I want to do is to transfer a file using scp from remote_machine(2) to remote_machine(1). How do I do this when there are these two steps involved?

I initially tried:

```
scp ./file.txt username@ip_of_remote_machine(1)
```

but it says

```
connection refused
```

I think this is because I need to go into the university network first.

I know my terminology isn't correct, but hopefully you understand what I mean.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/487613/scp-through-ssh-gateway-connection your problem looks like this issue for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you do not need to login to remote_machine(1) in two steps ever: the following command

```
  ssh -t me@universitygateway ssh me@remote_machine(1)
```

will do it for you, if you have enabled (as I seem to understand) passwordless login.

As for scp'ing, you can do it as follows:

```
 scp -o ProxyCommand="ssh me@universitygateway nc remote_machine(1) 22"  remote_machine(1):/path/to/file/to/download .
```

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful. I was prompted for the university gateway password, which I gave, but then I got the error message "nc: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known"

Comment: I have the authorisation keys set up on my laptop. But I supposed because I am copying from remote_machine(2) to remote_machine(1), I will be prompted for the passwords. But this is fine because I know the passwords. Doesn't the error message relate to something else?

Comment: and yes, I had "nc myusername@ip_of_remote_machine(1) 22"

Comment: Oh I tried it without the myusername@ and just the ip address. That worked! Thank you so much :)